# React.js Unresolved variable in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

I get an `unresolved variable` issue in the following code snippet:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleModalView = this.handleModalView.bind(this);
}

handleModalView() {
    this.refs.temp.handleShow();
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ModalView ref = 'temp' />
      <img src="some_image_source"
        className="SettingsLogo" onClick={this.handleModalView}
      />
  </div>
```

The IDE shows an `unresolved variable temp` in `handleModalView()`. However, my code works just fine.

**Edit 1**:
I have included the constructor that I have written. The error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a constructor in your component class and bind all of the member functions:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleModalView = this.handleModalView.bind(this);
    }

    handleModalView() {
      this.refs.temp.handleShow();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <ModalView ref = 'temp' />
          <img src="some_image_source"
            className="SettingsLogo" onClick={this.handleModalView}
          />
        </div>)
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestion. However, the error still persists. It is not affecting my code functionality in any way. My code is behaving just as expected. However, the IDE is pointing out that error. I am using **WebStorm** as my IDE.

Comment: @samirkumartripathy It sounds like the problem is with WebStorm, not your code.